# How do I create a vertical dividing line that is centered within the dividing margin of two columns using CSS?

Tags: html, css

The layout is two columns both 47.5% with a 5% margin on the left column. I want a vertical dividing line in the middle. I'm currently using border-right but the border is on the left edge of the margin so it is offset and not centred?.

I'm using Wordpress Divi theme but the following HTML/CSS is the crux of my problem:

```
<style>
.col-left {float:left;width:47.5%;margin-right:5%;border-right:3px solid #fff;height500px}
.col-right {float:left;width:47.5%;height500px}
</style>

<div class="col-left"></div>
<div class="col-right"></div>
```

Ben

Answer (score 0):

Change CSS `margin-right:2.5%; padding-right:2.5%;`

```
.col-left {float:left;width:47.5%;margin-right:2.5%;padding-right:2.5%;border-right:3px solid #fff;height500px}
```